# Quicker coding by combining CSS classes without using a preprocessor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When building forms,I need to indicate which are required. I follow this recipe:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk' style'color:red;font-size:9px;'></span>Label
```

My goal is to create 1 CSS class that uses the Bootstrap `glyphicon` class as well as bootstrap's `glyphicon-asterisk` But also allowing me to combine my own style rules.I have read that people use LESS mixins to do this. However I am asking if it is possible to go another route

The code looking something like this:

```
.req{
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
        display:inline-block;
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        font-style:normal;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size: 9px;
        font-color:red;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        content:"\2a";


    }
```

However for some reason this does not work.

This is the two bootstrap classes I wish to combine.

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\2a";
}
```

How can I achieve this without using LESS or SASS or any preprocessor So that when using the code:

```
<span class='req'></span>Label
```

I will receive the same output as the original one.

**Note** I do not want to overwrite the existing bootstrap classes. I want to create a new class in my own style.css that makes use of the two bootstrap classes.

Comment: In the solution you've marked, he hasn't combined the two rules in one... You still have two rules, but renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `font-color` CSS property, you have to use `color`. And if you want to use just one class you can use this code.

```
.req {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size:9px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.req:before {
  content: "\2a";
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Was in the process of submitting this answer myself.This seems to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the 'content: "\2a"' inside the .req however you can assign content only to :before or :after.